# How can I get all matched keys from redis using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

How Can I get all matched keys from list of keys stored in redis using Ruby on rails. I am using Ruby 2.5.1 version.

I used **SCAN** to query matched keys, but it returns 2 values always instead of 5. It returns all when I pass count. So How can I pass count in Ruby On Rails code?

**Without count return 2 value:**

```
  127.0.0.1:6379> SCAN 100 match *sa*
       1) "sasikala (6965)"
       2) "Zupaen sasi (6961)"
```

**With count return all (5) value:**

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SCAN 100 match *sa* count 100
           1) "Sasai (6965)"
           2) "Zupaen sasi (6961)"
           3) "Rosan (7000)"
           4) "Alisa (2363)"
           5) "Carissa (4455)"
```

**Ruby on rails code:**

```
keys = redis.scan(0, :match => '*' + name + '*')
```

Kindly provide your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use official [`redis-rb`](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) to handle redis connection, their [tests contain the answer](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/03e70f323400bb6e87653bec6eb62b43725d5f28/test/cluster_commands_on_keys_test.rb#L124-L130) on your question:

```
loop.inject([0, []]) do |(cursor, keys), _|
  cursor, new_keys = redis.scan(cursor, match: '{key}*')
  keys << new_keys
  break keys if cursor == '0'
  [cursor, keys]
end
```

Comment: Its not working getting "Redis::CommandError (ERR invalid cursor):"

Comment: Once again: this example is taken from their official tests, as I explicitly stated. Guess whether it’s working and your code around has glitches or vice versa.

Comment: Ok. let me try.

Comment: No, its not returning anything